# Unable to install gulp-jshint through npm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, npm-install

while installing gulp-jshint using node npm following error is showing "gulp-jshint@2.0.4 requires a peer of jshint@2.x but none was installed-UNMET peer dependency". Can anyone help to solve this problem. I am using windows 7 OS.

Comment: npm install -g jshint

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked!.

Answer (score 19):

Try executing the following command `npm install --save-dev jshint gulp-jshint`.

If that doesn't work, please check [this](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint/issues/131) github issue on their repo.

Answer (score 5):

`npm install -g jshint`

What this error is telling you is that you are missing a dependency for gulp-jshint: in this particular case, `jshint`

jshint prefers to be installed globally, hence the `-g` flag.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.0 of gulp-jshint module, jshint must be installed with gulp-jshint. https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint

```
npm install jshint gulp-jshint --save-dev
```